# How I can create a multi plot cases?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-science

I would like to present my plot in the form of multi plot cases as depicted bellow. My code was written using python and matlpotlib. The code and the figure is presented also below. I want also to replace beseline, Intervention with S1, S2, S3 and S4. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

 df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['1','2','3','4','5'],
       'S1': [74.92, 75.32, 79.64, 100, 101],
       'S2': [18.2,80,82,84, 90],
       'S3': [22,60,82,54, 70],
       'S4': [31,60,72,74, 90]
       })

 S1_lower_err = [73.3, 73.3, 75, 90, 108]
 S1_upper_err = [76, 80, 83.3, 107, 107]

 S1_lower_err = (S1_lower_err - df['S1']).abs() 
 S1_upper_err = (S1_upper_err - df['S1']).abs()

  yerr = [S1_lower_err, S1_upper_err]

  plt.errorbar('Time', 'S1', data=df, yerr=yerr, capsize=5, marker='s',            color='blue', markersize=4, linewidth=1, linestyle='--')

 S2_lower_err = [10, 70, 68, 90, 80]
 S2_upper_err = [40,80,90,90, 96]

 S2_lower_err = (S2_lower_err - df['S2']).abs() 
 S2_upper_err = (S2_upper_err - df['S2']).abs()

 yerr = [S2_lower_err, S2_upper_err]

 plt.errorbar('Time', 'S2', data=df, yerr=yerr, capsize=5, marker='o',  color='red', markersize=4, linewidth=1, linestyle='-')


 S3_lower_err = [12, 52, 80, 50, 65]
 S3_upper_err = [27,66,85,60, 76]

 S3_lower_err = (S3_lower_err - df['S2']).abs() 
 S3_upper_err = (S3_upper_err - df['S2']).abs()

  yerr = [S3_lower_err, S3_upper_err]

  plt.errorbar('Time', 'S3', data=df, yerr=yerr, capsize=5, marker='o',   color='green', markersize=4, linewidth=1, linestyle=':')

 S4_lower_err = [25, 50, 70, 70, 85]
 S4_upper_err = [33,66,77,80, 95]

 S4_lower_err = (S4_lower_err - df['S2']).abs() 
 S4_upper_err = (S4_upper_err - df['S2']).abs()

  yerr = [S4_lower_err, S4_upper_err]

  plt.errorbar('Time', 'S4', data=df, yerr=yerr, capsize=5, marker='o',  color='black', markersize=4, linewidth=1, linestyle='-.')

  plt.legend()
  plt.xlabel("Time")
  plt.ylabel("Performance")
  plt.ylim(-1, 120)
  plt.savefig('SixF.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
  plt.show()
```

The code generate the figure bellow.

[image]

Comment: I really hate been the guy who says you should look for another tool, but consider using Plotly, it it has a much better API and the plots are interactive and beautiful. https://plotly.com/python/subplots/. If matplotlib is a must, I think Subplots is what you are looking for https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: added error dictionaries so that they can be called each loop.

I rewrote your script so that the `df.Time` column increments each loop. Let me know if this is what you were thinking.

```py
%reset -f

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['1','2','3','4','5'],
   'S1': [74.92, 75.32, 79.64, 100, 101],
   'S2': [18.2,80,82,84, 90],
   'S3': [22,60,82,54, 70],
   'S4': [31,60,72,74, 90]
   })

df['Time'] = [int(i) for i in df['Time']]

lower_err_dict = {}
upper_err_dict = {}

lower_err_dict['S1'] = [73.3, 73.3, 75, 90, 108]
upper_err_dict['S1'] = [76, 80, 83.3, 107, 107]
lower_err_dict['S2'] = [10, 70, 68, 90, 80]
upper_err_dict['S2'] = [40,80,90,90, 96]
lower_err_dict['S3'] = [12, 52, 80, 50, 65]
upper_err_dict['S3'] = [27,66,85,60, 76]
lower_err_dict['S4'] = [25, 50, 70, 70, 85]
upper_err_dict['S4'] = [33,66,77,80, 95]

cols = ['S1','S2','S3','S4']
colors = ['blue','red','green','black',]

for col, col_color in zip(cols,colors):
    lower_err = lower_err_dict[col]
    upper_err = upper_err_dict[col]
    lower_err = (lower_err - df[col]).abs() 
    upper_err = (upper_err - df[col]).abs()
    yerr = [lower_err, upper_err]
    plt.errorbar('Time', col, data=df, yerr=yerr, capsize=5, marker='s', \
                 color=col_color, markersize=4, linewidth=1, linestyle='--')
    df.Time = df.Time + 5

plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Performance")
plt.ylim(-1, 120)
plt.savefig('SixF.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Also, the dataframe was making the `Time` column into an object so I had to convert them to ints so that they would increment properly.

Disregard the `reset` if you're not using jupyter notebooks.

[image]

Comment: thank you for you reply. The figure looks good but how i can edit the Time in a way to show 5 time interval for each plot. Also, can I separate them via bar to make a title for each one?

Comment: @Vincent [Here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html?highlight=shared%20axis) is an example of how to stack subplots with a shared axis. The example `Sharing both axes` stacks them vertically but you will be able to adapt this for your intended horizontal orientation.

Comment: Mr T knows what's up